# Mudar o css de uma div com mouseover Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Preciso que, se o mouse não estiver em cima de uma div, depois de 4 segundos ela desapareça, mudando o css. Como fazer isso com Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: Mas ela deve aparecer se o cursor estiver sobre ela novamente?

Comment: Não! @renan. Não precisa

Answer (score 3):

CSS:

```
.hide{
    display: none;
);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="my-div" style="background-color:#ff0000" >Minha Div</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function hideDiv(){
    $("#my-div").addClass('hide');
}

t = setTimeout(hideDiv,4000);

$("#my-div").mouseout(function(event){
    t = setTimeout(hideDiv,4000);
});

$("#my-div").mouseover(function(){

    if (t!=null) {
        clearTimeout(t);
    }
});
```

Comment: Parece que não está funcionando, amigo :(
https://jsfiddle.net/u8Lj7m7L/

Comment: Claro, esse código usa JQuery, Já que você colocou a tag na pergunta, subentendi que você incluiria a biblioteca. https://jsfiddle.net/7fadunso/

Comment: Desculpe amigo, apenas esquecí de incluir no fiddle.